# People fields data not saved when save by WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions SharePoint 2013 online

Tags: people-picker, save, newform

I have a list with a few people picker fields, i have a script on the new form:

```
function triggerPostback() {
       var saveButtonName = $('input[value$="Save"]').attr('name');
       WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(saveButtonName, "", true, "", "", false, true));
} 

function PreSaveItem() { 
    triggerPostback();
    return false;
}
```

Values in these people fields do not get saved when i press the save button. However editing the list item later and adding values does work.

Other non people picker fields do get saved.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replace this:

```
var saveButtonName = $('input[value$="Save"]').attr('name');
```

to

```
var saveButtonName = $('input[value="Save"]').name;
```

I have tested in SharePoint 2013:

[image: error when try get attr name from input]

I do not understand what the problem is this, but i got error: Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'. wft??? Documentation in JQuery is correctly, click here for 
 [more details](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
Perhaps the Jquery that you called does not support.

But anyway, hope this helps.